# Как узнать количество удаленных записей?

Tags: mysql

Как узнать, сколько записей я удалил? Например, при таком запросе

```
DELETE FROM `table`
WHERE `id` > 100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php 
  if(mysql_query("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = 25")) 
  { 
    echo (mysql_affected_rows()); 
  } 
?>
```

mysql_affected_rows() - возвращает количество рядов, затронутых последним INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE.

Comment: пора бы уже перестать использовать api mysql_

Comment: @nolka да тут скорее как пример, чем рабочее решение. PDO: http://docs.php.net/pdostatement.rowcount

Comment: А с чего вы взяли что впрос про php?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что вопрос не про php?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

после удаления.  [ссылка на документацию](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count)